# Error when using Kaggle CLI

Tags: python, kaggle

I originally installed the official Kaggle CLI [here](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api) a few weeks ago, and it was working fine. Now, however, whenever I try to pull a competition (or even list them) it appears to give me python errors. For example, when I put this:

```
$ kaggle competitions list
```

It gives me an attribute error and this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/envs/fastai/bin/kaggle", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kaggle/cli.py", line 48, in main
    out = args.func(**command_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kaggle/api/kaggle_api_extended.py", line 178, in competitions_list_cli
    competitions = self.competitions_list(page, search)
  File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kaggle/api/kaggle_api_extended.py", line 175, in competitions_list
    return [Competition(c) for c in competitions_list_result]
  File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kaggle/api/kaggle_api_extended.py", line 175, in <listcomp>
    return [Competition(c) for c in competitions_list_result]
  File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kaggle/models/kaggle_models_extended.py", line 23, in __init__
    parsed_dict = {k: parse(v) for k, v in init_dict.items()}
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I have tried to fix this by uninstalling and then reinstalling with pip, and when 
that didn't work I went and manually deleted the site packages in the active virtualenv directory, but no luck.

Python Version 3.6.3 (Anaconda). Kaggle API version 1.3.12.

I'm not sure what changed from a few weeks ago! Any ideas? I'm probably doing something dumb.

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the timing of your question, it looks like you may have hit a server glitch we were having. It should be fixed now. :)